# Why I got Excel syntax error while using nested Indirect?

Tags: excel-formula, nested

Working formula is:

```
=XMATCH("version";INDIRECT(CELL("contents";$A7)&"!B272"))
```

I must add 1 more nested INDIRECT, but I can't create proper syntax. **Not working code is:**

```
=XMATCH("version";INDIRECT(CELL("contents";$A7)&"!(INDIRECT("B"&Q22))"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into your error formula, guessing it might be supposed to be,

```
=XMATCH(
    "version"
),
{    INDIRECT(
        CELL(
            "contents"
        ),
{ $A7
        ) & "!" &
        INDIRECT(
            "B" & Q22
        )
    )
)
```

i.e. `=XMATCH("version";INDIRECT(CELL("contents";$A7)&"!"&INDIRECT("B"&Q22)))`